# How can I let templates choose which stylesheets are enqueued?

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-enqueue-style

My theme's `functions.php` hooks into `wp_enqueue_scripts` to register a couple of stylesheets that are used by various site pages. Here's a simplified version of my configuration:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {       
    // This stylesheet is used on *every* page
    wp_register_style("sitewide", get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/sitewide.css");
    wp_enqueue_style("sitewide");

    // These stylesheets are used by *some* pages
    wp_register_style("pagetype1", get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/pagetype1.css", array("sitewide"));
    wp_register_style("pagetype2", get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/pagetype2.css", array("sitewide"));
});
```

Every tutorial I've found so far enqueues every stylesheet from the callback itself, but I don't want to do this. I assume that this would cause *all* my stylesheets to be included on every page, which is not what I want. I only want to enqueue `pagetype1.css` if the underlying template for a certain page uses it.

Let's say that I want my front page to use the page type 1 stylesheet. My intuition would be to call `wp_enqueue_style("pagetype1");` in `front_page.php` right before including the header, which contains the `wp_head()` call. This doesn't do anything. The sitewide CSS on the other hand was included like I expected. What am I doing wrong?

I know that there is a [workaround](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61246/2159) out there, but I'd prefer that `front-page.php` retains control over which additional stylesheets are loaded.

---

**Edit**: This is what I ended up with after some discussion with *toscho*. I added this to `functions.php`:

```
// Enqueues a stylesheet handle or an array of stylesheet handles.
function mytheme_enqueueStyle($handles) {
    if (is_array($handles)) {
        add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() use ($handles) {
            foreach ($handles as $handle) {
                wp_enqueue_style($handle);
            }
        });
    } else if (is_string($handles)) {
        add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() use ($handles) {
            wp_enqueue_style($handles);
        });
    } else {
        wp_die("Unsupported parameter type.");
    }
}
```

Then I called `mytheme_enqueueStyle("pagetype1")` from `front-page.php` to enqueue the stylesheet. This way of doing things ended up being incompatible with WP Minify, though.

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` **inside** a template. The workaround in your link or the solution from toscho is the way to go. If you **really** want to include the script logic inside the template files you'll need to just use a `<script>`/`<style>` tag. This would be ok, if this is a custom development (enqueue script is primarly used for dependency management & for plugins to hook into the added scripts to exchange/remove or minify/combine them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the current template in your callback. This is a post meta field named `_wp_page_template`.

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() 
{
    // This stylesheet is used on *every* page
    wp_register_style("sitewide", get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/sitewide.css");
    wp_enqueue_style("sitewide");

    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    $template = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', TRUE );

    // now enqueue further stylesheets depending on the current template
});
```

Comment: This solution shifts control over which stylesheets are loaded from `front-page.php` to `functions.php`, which is why I didn't like the workaround I linked to from my original post. Isn't there a mechanism that lets `front-page.php` decide for itself?

Comment: @Pieter You could also check `is_front_page()` in the enqueue function, or add an action callback on top the `front-page.php`. I think there should be as little _logic_ in a template as possible.

Comment: Then I suggest a compromise: I add a function `mytheme_enqueueStyle($arrayOfStyleHandles)` to `functions.php` that creates the action callback for the template. `front-page.php` retains control and can enqueue additional stylesheets with a one-liner. Does this address your concerns?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. You can use `is_front_page()` wherever you want. But if you use `add_action()` in a template file, the code will be hard to maintain, because that’s not the first place to search for these things.

Comment: I was thinking about putting something along [these lines](http://pastebin.com/Q4agWZ3z) in `functions.php`. I'd call this function from `front-page.php` to enqueue `pagetype1` indirectly without using `add_action` in the template. Strangely this doesn't work, despite that calling `add_action` directly from the template file *did* work.

Comment: That should be a closure: `add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() use ( $handles ) {` …

Comment: Nice, that works! Sadly this form of stylesheet injection doesn't play nice with WP Minify, a plugin I use to compact JS/CSS files. Ah well... maybe I'm better off using the conventional solution then.