# Implement Google Maps JS on Wordpress

Tags: google-maps

I am looking to implement this code on my wordpress site as efficiently as possible

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

and I only want the JS to load on posts/pages that I will be using the map. Can't figure out how to start with this!

**EDIT:**

What if I use the enqueue part inside the function ? Is this a good construct?

```
function x_shortcode_google_map( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id'           => '',
    'class'        => '',
    'style'        => '',
    'lat'          => '',
    'lng'          => '',
    'drag'         => '',
    'zoom'         => '',
    'zoom_control' => '',
    'height'       => '',
    'hue'          => '',
    'no_container' => '',
    'api_key'      => ''
  ), $atts, 'x_google_map' ) );

  static $count = 0; $count++;

  $id           = ( $id           != ''     ) ? $id : 'x-google-map-' . $count;
  $class        = ( $class        != ''     ) ? 'x-map x-google-map ' . esc_attr( $class ) : 'x-map x-google-map';
  $style        = ( $style        != ''     ) ? 'style="' . $style . '"' : '';
  $height       = ( $height       != ''     ) ? 'style="padding-bottom: ' . $height . ';"' : '';
  $no_container = ( $no_container == 'true' ) ? '' : ' with-container';

  $js_params = array(
    'lat'         => ( $lat          != ''     ) ? $lat : '40.7056308',
    'lng'         => ( $lng          != ''     ) ? $lng : '-73.9780035',
    'drag'        => ( $drag         == 'true' ),
    'zoom'        => ( $zoom         != ''     ) ? $zoom : '12',
    'zoomControl' => ( $zoom_control == 'true' ),
    'hue'         => ( $hue          != ''     ) ? $hue : '',
  );

  $data = cs_generate_data_attributes( 'google_map', $js_params );

  $script_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js';

  if ( $api_key ) {
    $api_key = esc_attr( $api_key );
    $script_url = add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $api_key ), $script_url );
  }

  wp_register_script( 'cs-google-maps', $script_url );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'cs-google-maps' );

  $output = "<div id=\"{$id}\" class=\"{$class}{$no_container}\" {$data} {$style}><div class=\"x-map-inner x-google-map-inner\" {$height}></div>" . do_shortcode( $content ) . "</div>";

  return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'x_google_map', 'x_shortcode_google_map' );
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you'll be able to focus in on whether the page has the code or not, but you could use `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a condition as seen in [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61244/wp-enqueue-style-on-specific-page-templates).

Comment: If you have additional information or questions that pertains to your original questions, please click the "Edit" button above and add in that information. The Answer section ( below ) is specifically for answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all enqueue the Google Maps API js in the right way. look for a function which is hooked on `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue Google Maps API

```
function wp_mk_scripts() {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mk-maps-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mk-gmaps-function', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/maps.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_mk_scripts' );
```

then in your theme_folder/js/maps.js paste the map code between `<script></script>` tags in [Style Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

Now call the `<div id="map"></div>` div anywhere in the template to display the map.

Comment: yes but this loads the script everywhere.. What if I create a shortcode and put the script there like my answer below ?

Comment: wrap the `wp_enqueue_script()` function in `if ( is_singular() ) {}` to load the script only on posts and pages. i have updated the answer above.