# Wordpress Ajax Not Firing

Tags: ajax

I've been out of the WordPress game for a while now and I'm just getting back into it. I'm trying to practice calling a PHP function via Ajax but I'm not able to get the Ajax call to even fire (when checking in Google Chrome Developer).

I've got a funny feeling that this may have something to do with where I am adding the code. Currently I'm just adding all this in a HTML block verbatim as per below but I've got a funny feeling that this may be the issue?

Do I need to add the javascript via a plugin or similar?

My simple example is as follows:

```
<div id="output_div">
   <p>This is where output should go</p>
</div>

<select name="player_ID" id="player_ID">
  <option value="player1">player1</option>
  <option value="player2">player2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var valueCheck;
    jQuery("#player_ID").on("change", function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: "practice_ajax_function"
            },
            success: function (output) {
                jQuery("#output_div").html(output);
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying the Network tab in Chrom Dev Tools never displays a request being made, or that you've placed a breakpoint that never hits or some such? The JavaScript looks fine at a glance (though it's been some time since I've worked with jQuery) and it's location within the page shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: why both `on("change"` and `.change();` ..? that could be the problem. the first should be sufficient. also you haven't given us `practice_ajax_function` to know whether the problem is there.

Comment: also, an easy debug here would be to use `console.log(output);` in the success function.

Comment: The php function is fine, the issue is that the Ajax isn’t activating at all. I’ve found that if I add the JavaScript to the footer then it works perfectly. At the moment I’m adding this into a footer plug-in which means it gets loaded on every page. I’m still trying to work out how to include only on specific pages in the footer.

Comment: @Morts81 you should use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to load your JavaScript. If you want to enqueue your script only on specific pages, check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61244/wp-enqueue-style-on-specific-page-templates). If you want to print the JavaScript in the `<script>` tags instead, you can use `the_footer` action instead and then conditionally print your JavaScript.